# How to close Search Box if user clicks anywhere inside the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**What I want**
Currently, the search box opens and closes on clicking font awesome search icon. What I also want is to close search box if the user clicks anywhere inside the body.

**Screenshot**

[[image: check image here]

**My Code**

```html
<div id="searchbox">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-search" onclick="closeSearch()"; ></i>

<script>
function closeSearch() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchbox");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel Look the snippet in question

Comment: @melvin the snippet doesn't refer to the problem statement being asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned as click instead of focus, I haven't used blur event but implemented using click event.

```js
var isSearchBoxVisible = false;
var searchBox = document.getElementById("searchbox");
var skipClose;

function toggleSearchBox() {
  showSearchBox(!isSearchBoxVisible);
  skipCloseFn();
}

function showSearchBox(show=true){
   searchBox.style.display = show ? '' : 'none'; 
   isSearchBoxVisible = show;
}

function skipCloseFn(){
  skipClose = true;
}

showSearchBox(false);

// This can be directly given in HTML as well as given for outer search icon.
searchBox.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', skipCloseFn);
//Can be included only if necessary
searchBox.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  skipCloseFn();
});


document.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(!skipClose){
    showSearchBox(false);
  }
  skipClose = false;
});
```

```html
<button><i class="fa fa-search" onclick="toggleSearchBox()"; >icon</i></button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="searchbox">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">icon</i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Kindly just change above code so that searchbox remain hidden when page opens in browser and searchbox should only open when user clicks on fa fa-search icon. While Rest of code for closing  searchbox on click anywhere is OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use onblur on input box.

<div id="searchbox">
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" onblur="closeSearch()" name="q">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-search" onclick="closeSearch()"; ></i>
```

Comment: this solution closes the searchbox even when search icon inside the form is clicked. If this is the expected behavior, then the solution should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The onblur solution is a good one. But if you specifically want to require a click somewhere else in the page before closing, here is how to do it.

```html
<div id="searchbox">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-search" onclick="closeSearch()"; ></i>

<script>
function closeSearch() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchbox");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.onclick = function closeSearch(e) {
  const searchbox = document.getElementById('searchbox');
  if (!searchbox.contains(e.target) {
    searchbox.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function closeSearch() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchbox");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
var x = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
x.addEventListener('blur',function(evt){
document.getElementById("searchbox").style.display="none";
})

});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="searchbox">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-search" onclick="closeSearch()" ></i>
```